# Open URI in new TAB (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hey SO, is there anyway I can use `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(link), "_blank");` to open a URI in a new tab (not new window!) which is in the same instance of Internet Explorer.

Currently using SL3 and it seems that whether its a new tab vs. new window is based on browser options...

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing it properly by using "_blank". What that does is opens a new page in either a new tab or window depending on the user's settings:

- [Internet Explorer Settings](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/force-ie-to-open-link-in-new-tab/)
- [Firefox](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071022092634AAckvk2)
- [Safari](http://devinsblog.com/2009/07/19/safari-open-links-in-a-new-tab-by-default-mac/)

If you want to use a "hack" to get around this use [this link](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2008/05/quick-silverlight-tip-how-to-open-new.html) as a resource. It basically states that until a browser supports CSS3 you'll have to use a "hack" as a workaround:

- Internet Explorer -- [IWebBrowser2::Navigate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752134(VS.85).aspx) (use 0x1000 as the second parameter). Note: you have to have FULL TRUST MODE for this to work.

Comment: Also, how do get access to that interface? I don't know how to call that method... thanks!